# mikroC for ARM shows error while defining char variable

Tags: c, arm, stm32f4discovery, mikroc

I was trying to build my project but I got this error
I really don't understand the problem
I've tried to define the variable this way:

```
char*c=malloc(100);
```

and even this way:

```
char c;
```

[image]

Thanx

Comment: The error is most likely with the prior statement.  Also, please don't post links to screen shots.  Post the text in the question next time.

Comment: ^ comment out the line above and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring variables in the middle of a function is a C99 feature.  Your compiler may not support C99, or you may have to activate it with a switch.  Move the declaration to the top of the function.

Comment: The code does not even use `ch` so it could be removed entirely

Comment: Thanx Ben, I'll try it.
    Matt, take a closer look to the code